# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - find function not working with multiple classes

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to parse a certain section out of a website. I know my cURL statement is working and grabbing the raw HTML, because I can echo the results of the cURL command and see the web page contents on my server.

Here is what I am trying to parse out:

[image]

As you can see I am trying to parse out the "mw-scrollable-news.collection.j-tabPane.is-active.j-scrollViewport".

My code looks like this, I am using the exact CSS selector as is given on the site:

```
$html = str_get_html($results); // $results is the results of the cURL
$articleDivArray = $html->find('mw-scrollable-news.collection.j-tabPane.is-active.j-scrollViewport');
```

However when I do a:

```
print_r($articleDivArray);
```

It brings back an empty:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Here is what the raw HTML looks like:

```
<div class="collection__list j-scrollElement" data-type="Other" data-showTimestamp="True" data-showImage="False" data-showProvider="True" data-showByline="False" >
<div data-docid="1341791639" class="element element--article no-image j-scrollByElement">

    <div class="article__content">

            <h3 class="article__headline"><a class="link" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" data-source="seekingalpha.com" href="https://seekingalpha.com/news/3392514-new-age-beverages-enters-market-offering-agreement?source=marketwatch">New Age Beverages enters into At the Market Offering Agreement</a></h3>
        <p class="article__summary">New Age Beverages enters into At the Market Offering Agreement</p>


        <ul class="article__details">
            <li data-est="2018-09-24T13:51:00" class="article__timestamp">Sep. 24, 2018 at 1:51 p.m. ET</li>

            <li class="article__provider">on Seeking Alpha</li>

        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
<div data-docid="1341775218" class="element element--article no-image j-scrollByElement">

    <div class="article__content">

            <h3 class="article__headline"><a class="link" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" data-source="fool.com" href="https://www.fool.com/investing/2018/09/24/big-highs-wont-last-for-new-age-beverage-stock.aspx?source=djc&utm_campaign=article&utm_medium=feed&utm_source=djc">Big Highs Won&#x27;t Last for New Age Beverage Stock</a></h3>
        <p class="article__summary"></p>


        <ul class="article__details">
            <li data-est="2018-09-24T09:00:00" class="article__timestamp">Sep. 24, 2018 at 9:00 a.m. ET</li>

            <li class="article__provider">on Motley Fool</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

and so on etc...

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML that cURL gives you for that bit of page, too?

Comment: Hi Mike, I just added the HTML now.

Comment: Looking at that HTML, that looks nothing like what your queryselector is trying to pick up, so I assume your browser's showing the DOM _after_ JS has kicked in. Something which PHP's simple html dom parser can't do: it'll build the DOM from the HTML you give it, and that's all it'll do.

Comment: Id be willing to guess the `is-active` probably isnt there as that is most likely added by javascript. There could be other classes that are the same.

Comment: You mean the   `class="element element--article no-image j-scrollByElement"` is generated afterwards?

Comment: The query you show in your question is for an element called `<mw-scrollable-news>` with class `collection j-tabPane is-active j-scrollViewport`, which is very much not in the HTML we see from that cURL. So, yeah: whatever runs on the DOM post-load in the browser changes the document. If you want the summary texts from _this_ HTML, something like `p.article__summary` should be all you need.

Comment: Hi Mike, I've tried that (using a single class) but it brings back a gigantic recursive object that eats up all my memory and i have to keep re-booting my machine.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? A big picture doesn't tell us anything. Are you trying to get the text of the article summaries? The links?

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm trying to get everything between the <div class="article__content"> and it's closing </div> tag.